# Rebasing instead of merge in Visual Studio Code's git integration

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, there's a "Syncronize changes" button for Git repositories in the bottom left corner. By default,  it uses the "merge" functionality instead of rebase, which creates ugly merge commits.

How do you change this to do a rebase?

Comment: Just curious, why do you consider merge commits ugly?

Comment: Which button exactly, can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @Braca Screenshot is here: https://imgur.com/a/Ej7CVjQ (highlighted in yellow)

Comment: @evolutionxbox When you work with open source projects you want the history to be straight forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In versions 1.28 and later there is a [`git.rebaseWhenSync`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_always-rebase-when-running-sync) setting.

In older versions you can:

- run **Git:Sync (Rebase)** from Command Palette, or
- `git config pull.rebase true` from integrated terminal to rebase when you click **Synchronize Changes** button.

Comment: You can now Sync+Rebase since September2018 release https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_always-rebase-when-running-sync